# What does Atharva Veda 14.1.20 say?

Tags: women, identification-request, atharva-veda

What does Atharva Veda 14.1.20 say? Is it anyhow related to women?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Atharva Veda Suktas 14.1, 14.2 are all related to marriage. These marriage hymns deal with the symbolic marriage between knowledge typified by Surya and bridegroom Soma, who represents delight. These mantras point out the ideals for human marriage too.

Some mantras in these Suktas are still used in the rituals related to Hindu marriages even today. Departure of the bride from her father's home, for example, is mentioned in 14.1.17. Few of these mantras are spoken by the bride to the bridegroom and some others to the bride.

The [mantra 14.1.20](http://www.onlineved.com/atharva-ved/?mantra=20&language=1&kand=14&sukt=1), in particular, says:

> bhagastveto nayatu hasta grihAschinA tvA pra vahatAm rathena |
>  GrihAngaccha
>   grihapatni yathAso vasini tvam vidayamA vadAsi ||
>
> .........
>
> O Bride, Bhagah, the prosperity lead you from fathers family here
>   holding your hand and Arhvinau, the PrAna and ApAna carry you by
>   chariot, you go to the house of your husband, so that you may be the
>   mistress of the house, take all under your control. You always speak
>   with understanding.

So, all this is being said to the bride.

*Note1-I do not  have any other translations of this mantra for the time being.*

Comment: Thanks @Tezz.. I was not been able to see the first word.

Comment: Oh haha.. so u got the badge? @Tezz

Comment: Yes, strunk and white new badge... https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white?userid=5154